# how to find first character in a string (SQLITE)

Tags: sqlite

Found lots of statements with INSTR, but I get no such function: INSTR

I have version sqlite 3.7.5

```
SELECT INSTR('SQLite INSTR', 'I');
```

how to find first character in a string ?

Comment: Your query works in 3.8 (using dbfiddle), are you sure it isn't working in 3.7.5?

Comment: Yes I have the error before me and I checked the version through sql statement. Is there another way to do this. I mean sql exists since 1990 or so, but I can't do it. Disappointing.

Comment: Ok. found it . Old version seems to work with CHARINDEX.

Comment: I checked the release notes and instr() was included in 3.7.15 but it's kind of silly to complain when you are using a version from February 2011 yourself.

Comment: I use sqlite for an android app. So how can I upgrade the version ? I mean its just a file which I created in 2011.

Comment: Well, well, well. I can understand why you use such an old version. It's not the file that is relevant but what version of the sqlite library you are using.

Comment: Ok Thanks for explanation. I am using SQLite Maesto for manipulating the sqlite database. How do I tell this tool that I would like to use a newer version ?